# Cannot connect to the API using Volley

Tags: android, header, android-volley

I am trying to get a JSON request from an API using volley but it didn't seem to work. I did try another dummy API and it works but not for this one. The one I am currently using has headers with key and value. Also, on checking the API on postman, I saw that the JSON format begins with '[' so I am not sure what to put for the JSONObject. Also, I am not sure if I added the header right. I am very new to android and would definitely appreciate it if someone could help me out.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ExampleAdapter mExampleAdapter;
private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();

    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    parseJSON();
}
```

private void parseJSON() {
        String url = "http://apidev.travelhouse.world/api/v1/packages";

```
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject hit = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    String creatorName = hit.getString("holiday_name");
                    String imageUrl = hit.getString("primary_image");
                    String likeCount = hit.getString("package_price");

                    mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(imageUrl, creatorName, likeCount));
                }

                mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this, mExampleList);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {
        /** Passing some request headers* */
        @Override
        public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap headers = new HashMap();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("X-API-KEY", "CODEX@123");
            return headers;
        }
    };

    mRequestQueue.add(request);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `JsonObjectRequest` with:

```
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) { 
          for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {....}
    }
}
```

Comment: did that now it gives me an error on this line JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("");  What parameters do I pass there?

Comment: you dont need to pass parameters @Imran the onResponse method returns a JSONArray, just use that

Comment: i left it blank like u mentioned but i am getting an error saying getJSONArray(int) in JSONArray cannot be applied to   ()

Comment: JsonArray is simple array of Json Objects , to write like JSONObject myObject = response.get(0) -- for index 0 , then from myObject you have to take your elemnts out, do similar for alll elemnts

Comment: @Neha I am already doing that in the for loop in the code above

Comment: @Imran see the updated answer for a clue on where you went wrong

Comment: @Michael I tried the code above and it's giving me an error with the whole block of code. After the for loop JSONObject hit = response.getJSONObject(i); seems to be an error?

Comment: @Michael I've updated the code above with the changes you mentioned. Could you tell me if I went wrong somewhere?

Comment: @Imran youre still using JsonObjectRequest, you need to use JsonArrayRequest, read my answer again

Comment: @MichaelStoddart I updated the code again. It didn't give me any error but when I run the app it goes to the OnErrorResponse method. Could you check if I added the headers correctly?

Comment: @Imran No, I have answered your original question, try googling "how to add headers to volley jsonarrayrequest"

Comment: @MichaelStoddart I fixed the issue and your code started to work. On googling I had to add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in the AndroidManifest for some reason. It really didnt make much sense as to what that did but thanks for all the help. :)